# awk command with BEGIN does not work for me

Tags: awk

This is the simple awk command i am trying to write

```
grep "Inputs - " access.log | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "Inputs -" } ; { print $2 }'
```

i am trying to grep the file access.log for all the lines with "Input -" and trying to awk the part after the "Input -". This is giving the following error

```
awk: syntax error near line 1 
awk: bailing out near line 1
```

I am confused what is the issue with this, this should work!!!!

I have also tried the following and it does not work

```
grep "Inputs - " L1Access.log | awk -F='Inputs' '{print $1}'
```

Here is a sample input text file

```
This is line number 1. I dont want this line to be part of grep output
This is line number 2. I want this line to be part of grep output. This has "Input -", I want to display only the part after "Input -" from this line using awk
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It would be more useful if you showed us a sample of your input and explained what you're trying to do. There is rarely any good reason why you'd be using grep and awk together like that.

Comment: added sample input text

Comment: You have two "Input - ". The part after which "Input - " are you after?

Comment: the first occurrence in the line

Comment: And so your desired output would be `, I want to display only the part after "Input -" from this line using awk` ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you stated you want everything after the first instance "Inputs -", and since your grep is unnecessary:

```
nawk -F"Inputs -" 'BEGIN {OFS="Inputs -"} {line=""}; { for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) line=line OFS $i} {print line}' test
```

Your own answer will only print out the second element. In the event that you have more than one "Input -" you will be missing the remaining of the line. If you don't want the second (or third.. ) "Inputs -" in the output you could use:

```
nawk -F"Input -" '{ for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' test
```

Comment: Both will not work for me. The reason being what if the lines had multiple ' - '. Also i want to be able to have a field seperator which is more than 1 character

Comment: You stated that you wanted every thing after the "Inputs - ". Is there more than one "Inputs - " in the record? You also say you want to have a field seperator which is more than one character. The field seperator I've used here is three " - ", but I don't see what you would "want" that. Please add an example of your more complex record so we can properly help you.

Answer (score 1):

your problem cannot be reproduced here:

```
kent$  cat f
foo - xxx
foo - yyy
foo - zzz
fooba
kent$  grep 'foo - ' f| awk 'BEGIN { FS = "foo -"};{print $2}' 
 xxx
 yyy
 zzz
```

There must be something wrong in your awk codes. Besides, if you want to do a `grep` and `awk` to extract the part after your `Inputs -` you can use grep to do it in single shot:

```
kent$  grep -Po 'foo - \K.*' f
xxx
yyy
zzz
```

Answer (score 0):

OK folks i see what my issue is. I am using solaris and in solaris the awk does not have capability for regex, meaning it does not support more than 1 charater in the field seperator. So i used nawk

Please refer to this post
[Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257865/can-field-separator-in-awk-encompass-multiple-characters)

```
grep "Inputs - " L1Access.log | nawk 'BEGIN { FS = "Inputs -" }  { print $2 }'
```

this worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are not clear on what to get.  Here is a sample file:

```
cat file
test Inputs - more data
Here is nothing to get
yes Inputs - This is what we need Inputs - but what about this?
```

You can then use `awk` to get data:

```
awk -F"Inputs - " 'NF>1 {print $2}' file
more data
This is what we need
```

or like this?

```
awk -F"Inputs - " 'NF>1 {print $NF}' file
more data
but what about this?
```

By setting separator to `Inputs -` and test for `NF>1` it will only print lines with `Inputs -`

Comment: like i said in my other comments, awk -F works for only single charater field seperator in solaris. What you have said may work fine in other operating system, but not in solaris. You have to use nawk in solaris

Comment: @user1241438 are there any reason for not using `nawk` in solaris?