# How to use multiple, different characters as field separator in busybox awk?

Tags: awk, busybox

I'd like to split a string with BusyBox's `awk` using multiple and different characters. For example, spaces and slashes.

I read the answer of [Can field separator in awk encompass multiple characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257865/can-field-separator-in-awk-encompass-multiple-characters). It states that you should be able to pass "even a regex" as separator. But I'm unable to find the right syntax:

It is this output line of `ip` which I'm working on:

```
inet 192.168.2.1/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global eth0
```

I'd like to exact the IPv4 address:

```
ip -4 addr show dev eth0 | grep inet | awk -F'[ \/]' '{print $2;}'
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWK multiple delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204192/awk-multiple-delimiter)

Comment: Works just fine over here. Are you sure you're using GNU awk? Which version?

Comment: The answer of the duplicate question, does not work for me. I need the repetition operator.

Comment: @JamesBrown Damn it, I didn't notice BusyBox v1.22.1 (2017-02-24 07:41:34 UTC) multi-call binary.

Comment: Well, use gawk ie. the GNU awk.

Comment: @PatrickB. If any of the following answer helped you in your goal please accept/upvote the answer for closure by ticking right sign besides the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a regex, one needs to specify how many characters to match for. My regex was missing that:

```
ip -4 addr show dev eth0 | awk -F"[ /]+" '/inet/{print $3}'
```

is working. (Note, I'm running the busybox-version of awk)

The `+`-operator stands for at least one of the character list needs to match.

I also could remove the `grep`, thanks @PS.

Comment: Well, I just had to test it but on my Busybox at hand (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) and that `+` was not needed. You (awk) code worked as-is.

Answer (score 2):

Following code will check for the line containing a string `"inet"`. If this matched, then the second column in split into an array named `"a"`. and the first element of that array is printed.

```
ip -4 addr show dev eth0  |awk '/inet/{split($2,a,"/");print a[1]}'
```

Or you can try `grep` :

```
ip -4 addr show dev eth0 |grep -oP 'inet\s\K.*?[^/]+'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split`:

```
$ awk '{split($2,a,"/");print a[1]}' foo
192.168.2.1
```